# How to continue execution of Python script after evaluating a Click cli function?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

Say I have a basic click CLI command defined in a file `cli.py`:

```py
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--test-option')
def get_inputs(test_option):
    return test_option
```

Then another module script `test_cli.py`, from which I'd like to use the CLI defined in the above:

```py
from cli import get_inputs

print('before calling get_inputs')
print(get_inputs())
print('after calling get_inputs')
```

Then on the command line:

```
$ python test_cli.py --test-option test123
before calling get_inputs
```

So it appears that after a Click command is ran, the entire Python process finishes, and even if there are statements and expressions to be evaluated after that Click command in the script that  initiated the call, they will not be executed. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the Click documentation provides a good explanation for why this occurs, and how to change this behavior.

By default all commands inherit from `BaseCommand`, which defines a [`main`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.BaseCommand.main) method that by default exits upon successful completion with `sys.exit()`, which emits the `SystemExit` exception.

To change this behavior, one may disable what they term `standalone_mode` as [documented here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/exceptions/#what-if-i-don-t-want-that).

So for the example provided in my question, changing the line containing `get_inputs()` call in `test_cli.py` from `print(get_inputs())` into `print(get_inputs.main(standalone_mode=False))`, then invoking the script from the command line gives the desired behavior, like so:

```
$ python test_cli.py --test-option test123
before calling get_inputs
test123
after calling get_inputs
```